# div's background stays white after relative positioning

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div called `#main`. As I am working with angularjs, this div contains the content of multiple html pages. I tried a lot of css stuff to center this part within my html page.

This is the css of the html part:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    background-image: url("../images/whatever.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Now here is the styling of the div:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    display: block;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

But there is no opacity, it is just an ugly grey color. After some research I read something about positioning the div **absolute**.
I tried to use `position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;` and it works. The opacity is there - Why?

And is there a good way to center the div with relative positioning? Something like calc() on the width maybe?.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Obviously this would work: `width: calc(100vw - 100px);` combined with absolute positioning, but I still do not understand why the background-color is related to the positioning.

Comment: You should give a fixed width to #main like 960px then add something like margin: 0px auto; to align the div to center.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but I want to keep it let's say "responsive" so I don't want to use fixed pixels. Thats also the reason why I did the "alignment" with the padding in the `html` part.

Comment: I see. Can this help ? https://codepen.io/jonsuh/pen/duvgE

Comment: Not sure what you're after. I just did the example [On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyzxdjbz/) and even with your proposed working solution, it still renders grey - which kind of makes sense, as black with opacity behind a white background ought to become grey.

Comment: @CmdrSharp true story, but if you try to set for example `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` it is completely transparent and in my case it is not. I just want to understand why this happens.

btw: this div is included in another div without any styling, could this be the problem?

Comment: @bash0ne [Here it is with 0.5 opacity](https://jsfiddle.net/0na5hxtf/1/) and [here it is with 0 opacity](https://jsfiddle.net/0na5hxtf/2/). The latter is completely transparent. With the given code, that is the expected and actual result. If you get a different result when applying it in your code, there's something else going on that's not included here.

Comment: Hm, there is no other relevant styling for this element, checked the dev tools twice. I think I will just use the absolute position as a workaround for this (at least at my machine) "magic". Thanks in any case to all.

Comment: "btw: this div is included in another div without any styling, could this be the problem?" what is the styling for that div?

Comment: @Dejan.S as you quoted correct: there is no styling, i just use it to set a controller scope with angularjs

Comment: why not set controller on the `#main` div? as seen on the jsfiddles it has to be something else with your html and markup. what is the background image of html? The gray area has nothing to do with absolute position. Can you post your markup from html > body > all down to main div, also css for that.